# selectize.js doesn't work with remote url

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I'm using selectize like this:

```
$('#category_field').selectize({           
       valueField: 'name',             
       searchField: 'name',
       delimiter: "/",           
       options: [],
       load: function(query,callback)
       {    
           if(!query.length) return callback();          
           $.ajax({
               url: '/categories/autocomplete',
               type: 'GET',
               dataType: 'jsonp',
               data: {                                    
               },
               error: function() {
                   callback();
               },
               success: function(res) {
                   callback(res.movies);
               } 
           });              
       }           
   }
```

);

"#category_field" is just a form input of type text.

I verified that the ajax request is being made and the response from the server looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "568bee09421aa908fe000009"
    },
    "depth": 0,
    "name": "math",
    "parent_id": null,
    "parent_ids": [],
    "picture": {
      "url": "/uploads/category/picture/568bee09421aa908fe000009/Screenshot________________.png",
      "thumb": {
        "url": "/uploads/category/picture/568bee09421aa908fe000009/thumb_Screenshot________________.png"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

My problem is that the autocomplete dropdown menu doesn't even show, what to do ?

### Edit

I just wanted to mention that I'm using bootstrap 3 , the input field and the label for it are wrapped inside `<div class=field>...</div>`, this div is wrapped inside the form which is wrapped inside container inside panel.

Does this relate to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This response not looks like a valid JSON. Check console, or/and use trycatch

```
try { $.ajax(...) } catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```

And JSONP is crossDomain method, maybe you can try delete it.

Comment: "jsonp" was causing the error function to run so I tried deleting dataType as you said, The error function stopped running and the success function ran yet the autocomplete menu didn't appear, I also tried with dataType set to "json"

Comment: and the json online validator returned true(after replacing integervalue with a number and  etc) hmmm but I only put the object inside the array, are you saying the server should return json not array ?

Comment: I know it's a valid json, I copied the response into an online validator, the one I posted had mistakes sorry, I fixed them

Answer (score 0):

What i noticed

1. You are not passing any query to the service
2. You have to set preLoad true to load the options or have to set preLoad in focus to set the options initially

   or
3. You have to initialize the option with the array as like your response